# Active Directory Service Principal is giving Invalid value for key 'authentication'

Tags: azure-sql-server, azure-service-principal, spn

I am trying to execute a SSIS package where source is SQL Server and destination is Azure SQL with authentication "Active Directory Service Principal". ODBC driver is 17.8 and OLEDB driver is 18.5.

While executing the SSIS package, it fails for a script task with this error

> Invalid value for key 'authentication'

Below connection string is used:

```
Server=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;
    Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=False;
    User ID=clientid;Password=secrets;
    Authentication="Active Directory Service Principal";
    MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;
```

Script task is using `System.Data.SQLClient` library and targetting the .NET Framework v4.7

Comment: Hello @user3934763, may I know what is the microsoft.data.sqlclient version that you are using ? as its supported for 2.0.0+ , you can refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-service-principal-authentication)

Comment: can you please try using microsoft.data.sqlclient instead of System.data.sql client , you can install it from dotnet cli using command `dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient --version 3.0.1`

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT, SSIS package is using System.Data.SQLClient version 4.0.0, Is there any way we can use service principal authentication without using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient??

Comment: AFAIK,, system.data.sqlclient only supports for SQL auth or AAD user auth but not service principal or other authentication methods , so if you want to use service principal or others like device code flow or managed identity then you need to use microsoft.data.sqlclient

Comment: Hi @AnsumanBal-MT, I have GACed and used Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient dll in script task. But now package is failing for error

Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Also not able to GAC this dll. Error 
Failure adding assembly to the cache: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Comment: hello @user3934763, have you installed the package `Microsoft.data.sqlclient`?

Comment: PLease refer this : [MS QA thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/434478/unable-to-load-dll-39microsoftdatasqlclientsnix64d.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SSIS package is using System.Data.SQLClient version 4.0.0, Is there
> any way we can use service principal authentication without using
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient??

`System.Data.SQlClient` only supports **SQL authentication** or **AAD User Account Authentication** .

So, if you want to use **Service Principal** or other authentication Methods then you should use `Microsoft.Data.SQLClient` as it is supported by it from version `2.0.0+`.

**Command to install `Microsoft.Data.SQLClient` package from dotnet CLI:**

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient --version 3.0.1
```

**Then you can use the below :**

```
string ConnectionString = @"Server=servername.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Database=testdb; User Id=AppId; Password=secret";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
}
```

**Reference:**

[Using Azure Active Directory authentication with SqlClient - ADO.NET Provider for SQL Server | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#using-active-directory-service-principal-authentication)